# how to show a bounce effect when scrolling is disabled in a recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

I have a `recyclerview` which scrolls horizontally. I have disabled scrolling the `recyclerview` when user click on an item. Now if the user try to scroll the list when its lock I want to show a bounce effect that he/she cannot scroll further.

**For example:**

I have a list of `10 items` and user clicked on the `5th item`. Now the scroll is locked and when the user try to scroll I want to show a bounce effect that the user can't scroll.

Here is my custom `LinearLayoutManager`:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import android.util.AttributeSet


class CustomLinearLayoutManager : LinearLayoutManager {
  private var isScrollEnabled = true

  constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

  constructor(context: Context, orientation: Int, reverseLayout: Boolean) : super(context, orientation, reverseLayout)

  constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)


  fun setScrollEnabled(flag: Boolean) {
    this.isScrollEnabled = flag
  }

  override fun canScrollHorizontally(): Boolean {
    //Similarly you can customize "canScrollHorizontally()" for managing horizontal scroll
    return isScrollEnabled && super.canScrollHorizontally()
  }
}
```

Here is my recyclerview enable/disable scroll code:

```
val layoutManager = CustomLinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
layoutManager.setScrollEnabled(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use bouncy recyclerview to achieve this functionality and use below link to user it [BoucncyRecyclerview](http://hello%20!!%20you%20can%20use%20bouncy%20recyclerview%20to%20achieve%20this%20functionality) or else you can use Overscroll effect of recyclerview using [OverScroll effect of recyclerview](https://github.com/EverythingMe/overscroll-decor)

Comment: But the user can be at the middle of the list also. This will work when the user reaches the end or start of the recyclerview list.